# Transforming multiindex to row-wise multi-dimensional NumPy array.

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Suppose I have a MultiIndex DataFrame similar to an example from the [MultiIndex docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html).

```
>>> df 
               0   1   2   3
first second                
bar   one      0   1   2   3
      two      4   5   6   7
baz   one      8   9  10  11
      two     12  13  14  15
foo   one     16  17  18  19
      two     20  21  22  23
qux   one     24  25  26  27
      two     28  29  30  31
```

I want to generate a NumPy array from this DataFrame with a 3-dimensional structure like

```
>>> desired_arr
array([[[ 0,  4],
        [ 1,  5],
        [ 2,  6],
        [ 3,  7]],

       [[ 8, 12],
        [ 9, 13],
        [10, 14],
        [11, 15]],

       [[16, 20],
        [17, 21],
        [18, 22],
        [19, 23]],

       [[24, 28],
        [25, 29],
        [26, 30],
        [27, 31]]])
```

**How can I do so**?

Hopefully it is clear what is happening here - I am effectively unstacking the DataFrame by the first level and then trying to turn each top level in the resulting column MultiIndex to its own 2-dimensional array.

I can get half way there with

```
>>> df.unstack(1)
         0       1       2       3    
second one two one two one two one two
first                                 
bar      0   4   1   5   2   6   3   7
baz      8  12   9  13  10  14  11  15
foo     16  20  17  21  18  22  19  23
qux     24  28  25  29  26  30  27  31
```

but then I am struggling to find a nice way to turn each column into a 2-dimensional array and then join them together, beyond doing so explicitly with loops and lists.

I feel like there should be some way for me to specify the shape of my desired NumPy array beforehand, fill it with `np.nan` and then use a specific iterating order to fill the values with my DataFrame, but I have not managed to solve the problem with this approach yet .

---

**To generate the sample DataFrame**

```
iterables = [['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']]
ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8*4).reshape((8, 4)), index=ind)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) and [swapaxes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) magic -

```
df.values.reshape(4,2,-1).swapaxes(1,2)
```

Generalizable to -

```
m,n = len(df.index.levels[0]), len(df.index.levels[1])
arr = df.values.reshape(m,n,-1).swapaxes(1,2)
```

Basically splitting the first axis into two of lengths `4` and `2` creating a `3D` array and then swapping the last two axes, i.e. pushing in the axis of length `2` to the back (as the last one).

Sample output -

```
In [35]: df.values.reshape(4,2,-1).swapaxes(1,2)
Out[35]: 
array([[[ 0,  4],
        [ 1,  5],
        [ 2,  6],
        [ 3,  7]],

       [[ 8, 12],
        [ 9, 13],
        [10, 14],
        [11, 15]],

       [[16, 20],
        [17, 21],
        [18, 22],
        [19, 23]],

       [[24, 28],
        [25, 29],
        [26, 30],
        [27, 31]]])
```

Comment: This is perfect, and easily generalizable if using the length of the levels instead of hardcoding. Thanks Divakar!

Comment: @EricHansen Added a generalized version.

Comment: Awesome. I'd be happy to ask this in another question, or award a bounty, but out of curiosity and to try and understand your method, I tried to slightly modify my problem. That is, have `[[[0, 4], [8, 12], [16, 20], .....` instead - form the 3d array by grouping by the second multi-index level then moving _down_ instead of across. But I couldn't adapt your solution easily - do you think this is a trivial change to the problem or requires a different soln. entirely?

Comment: @EricHansen I am guessing instead of `.swapaxes(1,2)`, we need `.transpose(2,0,1)`.

Comment: Note, that this only works if you have a full combination of first * second multiindex, and they are sorted in the proper order, which happens to be the case in the example.

Answer (score 1):

to complete the answer of @divakar, for a multidimensionnal generalisation :

```
# sort values by index
A = df.sort_index()

# fill na  
for idx in A.index.names:  
  A = A.unstack(idx).fillna(0).stack(1)

# create a tuple with the rights dimensions
reshape_size = tuple([len(x) for x in A.index.levels])

# reshape
arr = np.reshape(A.values, reshape_size ).swapaxes(0,1)
```